# isPrefixOf & isSuffixOf

Tags: haskell, reinventing-the-wheel

Please review and suggest improvements for my `isPrefixOf` implementation.

```
isPrefixOf' :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a] -> Bool
isPrefixOf' [] _ = False
isPrefixOf' _ [] = False
isPrefixOf' (x:xs) (y:ys) 
  | null xs && x == y = True
  | x == y            = isPrefixOf' xs ys
  | otherwise         = False
```

Also, I wrote `isSuffixOf` baesd on `isPrefixOf`. It seems debatable to me whether it's clear to understand. Is it idiomatic?

```
isSuffixOf' :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a] -> Bool
isSuffixOf' xs ys = isPrefixOf' (reverse xs) (reverse ys)

--isSuffixOf "foobar" "bar" == isPrefixOf "raboof" "rab"
```

Answer (score 2):

That is very idiomatic Haskell code. The only thing I'd mention is that the empty list *is* a prefix of everything, so your first case should be

```
isPrefixOf' [] _ = True
```

With that change, you can remove

```
  | null xs && x == y = True
```

since it will be correctly handled by

```
  | x == y = isPrefixOf' xs ys
```

As for implementing `isSuffixOf` in terms of `inPrefixOf`, you're in good company; [that's how `Data.List` does it](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/src/Data-List.html#isSuffixOf).